# JavaScript | AngularJS | UI-Router: $urlRouterProvider Redirect With Parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router, routeparams

#### The Problem...

The Implementer should have the ability to write simple redirects using `$urlRouterProvider.when` to invoke another state *with the same, expected URL-parameters*:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/hook/route', '/that/other/route');
```

This should provide the correct `$sateParams` needed for the target state. For example, if the URI `/hook/route?token=X` is called, the target state should have `$stateParams.token === 'X'` -- given that this parameter *is* configured within the `$stateProvider` ({... url: '/that/other/route?token' ...});

The conventional way [in Stackoverflow-land] looks like the following:

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .when('/hook/route', redirect)
    .otherwise('/');

function redirect($state, $stateParams) {
    $state.go('app.otherState', { token: $stateParams.token });
}
```

This seems **very** overkill for a simple *redirect-with-parameters* action -- especially if many redirects are needed.

The answer I'll provide below shows a very-low-overhead approach, which unfortunately, has not been spot-lighted in other StackOverflow threads regarding this topic...

Answer (score 2):

#### ... Solution

Match your URI's parameters against those expected by your target state:

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .when('/hook/route?token', '/route?token')
    .otherwise('/');
```

Cheers!